# Forzar el juego de caracteres al ejecutar un script via sqlplus

Tags: oracle-11g, codificación, sqlplus

Tengo una macro en Excel que genera un fichero SQL plano con sentencias INSERT para ser ejecutadas desde un formulario Oracle Forms, mediante una invocación a sqlplus. Soy la desarrolladora y en mi equipo todo funciona correctamente, pero la gente que utiliza este mecanismo tiene problemas con la codificación al ejecutar las inserciones. El proceso es el siguiente: se ejecuta la macro sobre un Excel relleno. La macro genera ficheros .SQL con una serie de instrucciones para cargar los datos en BD. Al abrir el fichero SQL los caracteres se ven correctamente (acentos y simbolos especiales).

```
SET ECHO OFF;
DELETE FROM TABLATEMP;
INSERT INTO TABLATEMP ( CAMPOS ) VALUES ('E126',301,'Un código de producto','Una descripción con acentos y símbolos especiales como Ø',1,Null,Null,0,0,Null,7);
...
COMMIT;
QUIT;
```

Después se árranca el ERP, y desde la pantalla correspondiente, al pinchar en un botón se lanza una sentencia:

```
HOST('SQLPLUS USU/PASS@INSTANCIA @' || v_nomfichero );
```

La codificación de la BD es:

PARAMETER  VALUE

NLS_LANGUAGE    **SPANISH**

NLS_TERRITORY   **SPAIN**

NLS_CURRENCY    ?

NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    SPAIN

NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  ,.

NLS_CHARACTERSET    **WE8MSWIN1252**

NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN

NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD/MM/RR

NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   SPANISH

NLS_SORT    SPANISH

NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF

NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF

NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR

NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD/MM/RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR

NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   ?

NLS_COMP    BINARY

NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE

NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE

NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16

NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.4.0

El characterset debe ser el que se ve para permitir la compatibilidad con la versión de OracleForms con la que está desarrollado el ERP (6i). Yo tengo instalada la herramienta Developer para Oracle Forms y Reports 6i, así como el SqlClient de la versión 11 y una instancia de OracleXE11 y probablemente algún resto de alguna cosa más. Los usuarios tienen instalado el runtime de Oracle Forms y Reports así como el cliente Sql de la versión 11.

¿Alguien sabe como puedo forzar la ejecución del script para que utilice una codificación correcta? O alguna acerca de lo que puedo hacer en los equipos de los usuarios para asegurarme de que la codificación con la que se conectan a la BD es la correcta. Los usuarios son pocos, por lo que puedo alterar ficheros en sus equipos si hace falta.

Muchas gracias.

**EDIT:** He probado añadiendo un ALTER SESSION al comienzo del script y tampoco me ha funcionado. El Alter Session ha sido:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= 'SPANISH' NLS_TERRITORY= 'SPAIN' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY= 'SPAIN' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ',.' NLS_CALENDAR= 'GREGORIAN' NLS_DATE_FORMAT= 'DD-MM-RR' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= 'SPANISH' NLS_SORT= 'SPANISH'
```

Los valores los he rellenado tal y como están definidos en la BD (la lista de valores que he colocado más arriba).

Answer (score 1):

Al iniciar la sesión contra la base, podrías forzar el uso de los caracteres, a los deseados. Te paso un ejemplo:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= 'AMERICAN' NLS_TERRITORY= 'AMERICA' NLS_CURRENCY= '$' NLS_ISO_CURRENCY= 'AMERICA' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= '.,' NLS_CALENDAR= 'GREGORIAN' NLS_DATE_FORMAT= 'DD-MON-RR' NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE= 'AMERICAN' NLS_SORT= 'BINARY'
```

Esto lo hace solo para la sesión actual. El usuario que se conecta debe tener permisos de DBA para hacerlo.
Espero te sirva

Comment: Lei en algún sitio que no se podía hacer un Alter Session y ni lo intenté, supongo que lo leeria mal :( Hago la prueba y actualizo.

Comment: Por fin he conseguido probar tu sugerencia y no me ha funcionado. Actualizo la pregunta con los resultados.